# Hide a recurring folder

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, directory, permalinks

For some reason, I keep getting an empty folder called "blog" generated on my server. No idea why, I've asked on the WP.org forum, but to no avail - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/directory-being-created?replies=14

This screws up my pretty permalinks, since instead of the link to /blog showing my blog, it just shows an empty folder.

Whilst I wait to resolve my issue, is there a way to make .htaccess forward the blog folder url to my actual blog page?

Current .htaccess below:

```
RewriteEngine on

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Did you create a page called "blog" in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your .htaccess to include the following

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
#if it is the blog folder also send it to WordPress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/?
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Amazing. I'm pretty irritated I didn't think of this months ago!